# Altium Designer PCB editor text too small

Tags: pcb, altium

I have this annoying issue with Altium where **the text of the net names on pads, vias and tracks in the PCB editor (and in pcblibs) is way too small**. I looked all over the defaults, tried resetting everything to the defaults, but no luck. I use version 20.0.10 (and hate it)

Does anyone know how I can make the text bigger?

[image]

Comment: Try going into Windows and change your global font.   In Windows 10 I found it works best to use a 'custom' font of about 150% rather than pick one of the standards.   You'll have to restart your computer to see if it works for you.

Comment: Nope, changing that didn't work. I still wasn't able to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for Preferences -> PCB Editor -> Board Insight Display -> Min/Max Font Size

[image]